# add pvalue bars to facet plot with "fill" sub-group

Tags: r, plot, facet, p-value

I'm looking for a solution since too much time without finding it, so it's time to ask for some help...

I would like to add pValue to boxplots organized with facet_wrap (ggplot2). Similar to what you obtain with the script I add to this post (the first part of the script is the exemple of what I want and it's working well for 1 plot, the second part is related to facet and doesn't work).

I would like to add pvalue between all "dose" values of "OJ", same for "VC", but also between, for exemple "dose"=1 of OJ and VC (as in the plot). It's working well for 1 plot, but not in facet_wrap. The error message is:
Error: Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 6 rows.
x Assigned data has 60 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Thanks for your help (if only...)

The script:

```
 ################# DATAFRAME
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth
vec <- c("A","B")
df$dose <- as.character(df$dose)
df$facet <- rep(sample(vec, 2),replace=T, nrow(df)/2)
view(df)
################### STAT
df_pval <- df %>%
  rstatix::group_by(dose) %>%
  rstatix::wilcox_test(len ~ supp) %>%
  rstatix::add_xy_position()
df_pval2 <- df %>%
  rstatix::group_by(supp) %>%
  rstatix::wilcox_test(len ~ dose) %>%
  rstatix::add_xy_position(x = "supp", dodge = 0.8)
################### PLOT
plotx <- ggplot(df, aes(x = supp, y = len)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = dose)) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(df_pval,
                     label = "{p}",
                     color = "dose",
                     fontface = "bold",
                     step.group.by = "dose",
                     step.increase = 0.1,
                     tip.length = 0,
                     bracket.colour = "black",
                     show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(df_pval2,
                     label = "{p}",
                     color = "black",
                     fontface = "bold",
                     step.group.by = "supp",
                     step.increase = 0.1,
                     tip.length = 0,
                     bracket.colour = "black",
                     show.legend = FALSE)
plot(plotx)
################### STAT FACET
  df_pval3 <- df %>%
    rstatix::group_by(dose, facet) %>%
    rstatix::wilcox_test(len ~ supp) %>%
    rstatix::add_xy_position()
  df_pval4 <- df %>%
    rstatix::group_by(supp, facet) %>%
    rstatix::wilcox_test(len ~ dose) %>%
    rstatix::add_xy_position(x = "supp", dodge = 0.8)

  print(df_pval)
  print(df_pval2)
###################### PLOT FACET
ploty <- ggplot(df, aes(x = supp, y = len)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = dose)) +
  facet_wrap(~df[,4]) + stat_pvalue_manual(df_pval3,
                                           label = "{p}",
                                           color = "dose",
                                           fontface = "bold",
                                           step.group.by = "dose",
                                           step.increase = 0.1,
                                           tip.length = 0,
                                           bracket.colour = "black",
                                           show.legend = FALSE) +
                        stat_pvalue_manual(df_pval4,
                                           label = "{p}",
                                           color = "black",
                                           fontface = "bold",
                                           step.group.by = "supp",
                                           step.increase = 0.1,
                                           tip.length = 0,
                                           bracket.colour = "black",
                                           show.legend = FALSE)
plot(ploty)
```

Comment: Using `facet_wrap(.~facet)` instead of  `facet_wrap(~df[,4])` I do not get any error.

Comment: @JKupzig Waow, so fast. Thank you very much, it's working very well. Please, could you explain me what is the difference between these both "facet_wrap", because both are doing the same facetting, but yours is also working for pvalue positioning (and I don't know what means ".~") ?

Comment: .~ means that you are referring to the object you are plotting. And facet is only the column name to use to split the plot. Because your df_pval has also a column named facet, facet_wrap "knows" how to split up everything. In your solution this is not the case, you are using only a column in df. So facet_wrap does not know how to deal with the df_pval-object.

Comment: @JKupzig I tried many things and waste too many time with this... thank you again!